# jQuery: Add class to all blockquote elements that do not have "cite" element and do not have that class

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, how can I select all `blockquote` elements that do not have `cite` element inside and do not have class `testClass` - and *add* that class to those blockquote elements.
For example, it would select this blockquote (and add class `testClass`):

```
<blockquote>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum...
    </p>
</blockquote>
```

but **not** this (because it already has that class):

```
<blockquote class="testClass">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum...
    </p>
</blockquote>
```

and **not** this (because it has `cite` element):

```
<blockquote>
    <cite>Originally posted by John Doe:</cite>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum...
    </p>
</blockquote>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.filter` , `!` (not) , `hasClass` , `find().length`

```js
$('blockquote').filter(function(){
  return !$(this).hasClass('testClass') && !$(this).find('cite').length
}).addClass('testClass');
```

```css
.testClass{
  background : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<blockquote>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum...
    </p>
</blockquote>

<blockquote class="testClass">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum...
    </p>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
    <cite>Originally posted by John Doe:</cite>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum...
    </p>
</blockquote>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('blockquote').each(function(i, item) {

    var $item = $(item);

    if( !$item.hasClass('testClass') && !$item.find('cite').length )
    {
        $item.addClass('testClass');
    }

});
```